# How to solve "Unable to apply data patch" when upgrading?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, security-patch

I'm upgrading my Magento 2.3.2 to Magento 2.3.5 and I'm receiving this following error during upgrade:

```
Module ‘Magento_Wishlist’: Unable to apply data patch 
Magento\Wishlist\Setup\Patch\Data\CleanUpData for module Magento_Wishlist. Original exception 
message: Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error
```

how could I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Probably happening because you have bundle products in your store.**

Merchants who encounter this error after installing Magento 2.3.5 should upgrade to Magento 2.3.5-p1.

Merchants who encounter this error after installing Magento 2.3.4-p1 should upgrade to Magento 2.3.4-p2.

Reference: [Wishlist error during upgrade to Magento versions 2.3.4-p1 or 2.3.5](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042621771).

Comment: 1+ Right...........

Comment: @RkRathod I am facing this error while upgrading 2.3.4 to 2.3.5 so should i upgrade directly to 2.3.6

Comment: Yes, probably you will face the same error in 2.3.6 like some module upgrade needed, but then you will be in the latest version.

Comment: https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042621771-Wishlist-error-during-upgrade-to-Magento-versions-2-3-4-p1-or-2-3-5-

Answer (score 3):

Getting below error at the time of bin/magento setup:upgrade

Module ‘Magento_Wishlist’: Unable to apply data patch Magento\Wishlist\Setup\Patch\Data\CleanUpData for module Magento_Wishlist. Original exception message: Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error

***Solution:***

The simplest – delete OR move the

> CleanUpData.php

file from the vendor folder

/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Setup/Patch/Data/CleanUpData.php

Comment: https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042621771-Wishlist-error-during-upgrade-to-Magento-versions-2-3-4-p1-or-2-3-5-

Answer (score 0):

Unable to apply data patch Sample\Module\Setup\Patch\Data\AddCustomDataPatch for module Sample_Module. Original exception message: Entity exist with same values.

this is an issue may also occur when you are trying to insert the data and that field is unique in DB, duplication is not allowing so it throw this error

delete that specific row from table.

> delete from my_custom_table where value="unique_value";

Answer (score -1):

Run these commands from the root directory of your store.

composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.5-p1 --no-update

composer update

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f